# eigenvectors of a matrix with known eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0&1&0&0\\
        0&0&0&2\\
        0&0&2&0
        \end{matrix}
    $$

This matrix has eigenvalues 1, 2, & -2, I've solved the eigenvectors for 1 & 2, but not for -2. Subtracting (-2) from the diagonal produces:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0&3&0&0\\
        0&0&2&2\\
        0&0&2&2
        \end{matrix}
    $$

Solving the augmented matrix (not shown) gives me

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 \\
        0\\
        -1\\
        1\\
        \end{matrix}
    $$

but the answer is
   $$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 \\
        0\\
        1\\
        -1\\
        \end{matrix}
    $$

I've checked multiple sources and I'm wrong but I don't understand why.

Comment: Neither of the vectors you mention are eigenvectors of the given matrix.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez fixed it, I'm still confused about that negative though

Comment: Eigenvectors are not unique; eigenspaces are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Amzoti` said, "eigenvectors are not unique".

If you try to solve the following eigenproblem for $\textbf{x}=(x,y,z,t)$:
$$M\bf{x}=-2\bf{x}$$
where $M$ is your matrix, $-2$ is one of the eigenvalues and $\bf{x}$ is the eigenvector you're having trouble with, you'll find that $$z=-t$$

Therefore, the two eigenvectors you mention are equivalent, and a general expression for the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-2$ is:
$$\mathbf{x}=(0,0,k,-k),\quad k\in\mathbb{R}^*$$

Comment: Pedantically speaking, when $k=0$ you don't have an eigenvector. This is quite pedantic, though. +1.

Comment: @Ian Is it because the columns are linearly independent?

Comment: @malabeh No no, my nitpick is because $0$ is by definition not an eigenvector. (Slightly confusingly, it *is* a member of an eigenspace, even though it is not an eigenvector.)

Comment: @Ian Ok, when can 0 be an eigenvalue then? Can it?

Comment: @malabeh $0$ can definitely be an eigenvalue. For example all eigenvalues of the zero matrix are zero.

Comment: @Ian Fair point, I made the correction.

Comment: @Demosthene I'm not sure what you mean in that second sentence; there are plenty of matrices which have zero as an eigenvalue but the multiplicity is not full. For instance $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

you can take advantage of the block structure of the matrix. you have two $2 \times 2$ matrices $B$ and $C$ where $B = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}, C = \pmatrix{0&2\\2&0}.$  $B$ has eigenvalues $1,1$  but only one eigenvector $(1,0)^T$ and $C$ has eigenvalues $-2, 2.$ the eigenvector corresponding to $-2$ is $(1,-1)^T$ and an eigenvector corresponding to $2$ is $(1, 1)^T.$

the eigenvalues of the mattrix $\pmatrix{B&0\\0&C}$ are $1,1, -2, 2.$ an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ is $\pmatrix{1&0&0&0}^T,$  an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-2$ is $\pmatrix{0&0&1&-1}^T$ and an
eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$ is $\pmatrix{0&0&1&1}^T$